# Mocking Framework with C# 4.0 Support?

Tags: mocking, c#-4.0

Anybody know of a mocking framework that supports C# 4.0?  Doesn't matter which one ATM, just need something that will work.

Comment: I wrote one that makes playful jabs about your coding prowess. It's really more good-natured than derisive, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you are looking for something that explicitly use new features of C# 4.0 (and I can't think what that would be off the top of my head), you can use most of the current dynamic mocks that exist for .NET 3.5.

I've only used [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) on .NET 4.0 (no problems), but I see no reason RhinoMocks and other libraries shouldn't work either.

Most dynamic mock libraries are just .NET libraries, so the backwards compatibility of .NET will (normally) ensure that they still work even if you upgrade to a newer version of the CLR/BCL.

The exception that proves the rule might be TypeMock, since it works in an entirely different way, but I have no experience with it, so I can't say one way or the other if it will work with C# 4.0.

Comment: I've tried to use Moq on .NET 4.0... but in my case Moq.Mock was not be able to resolved by MS VS2010... don't know why...

Answer (score 2):

We're using [NMock](http://www.nmock.org/) and [Rhino 3.5](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) and it seems to work fine for us